# AutoMapper - Array of int to list of custom objects

Tags: c#, automapper

Starting from these example:

```
public class A
{
    public int[] ArrayOfIds { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<C> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a mapping from A to B, where B contains a list of C objects, identified with ids of A.

How can I configure AutoMapper to achieve this?

Comment: Hey! Glad you ask, but maybe you should **try something first** and come back with the issues you find, otherwise you're asking for the members to code for you. Have you checked this guide? https://www.infoworld.com/article/3192900/c-sharp/how-to-work-with-automapper-in-c.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:
1. Create Map from `int` to `C`, so that you can do casting on `int[]`
2. Create Map from `A` to `B`

```
A a = new A();
a.ArrayOfIds = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<int, C>().ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src));
    cfg.CreateMap<A, B>().ForMember(dest => dest.MyList, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.ArrayOfIds));
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var b = mapper.Map<B>(a);
```